# onKeyUp event in textbox using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a text box that takes values entered by the user.. When a value is entered in the text box and enter is pressed, the value disappears from the box. So, I'm implementing an `onKeyUp` on the textbox so the value is confirmed. I don't think I'm using the `onKeyUp` event in the correct place. [CodeSandBox for testing](https://codesandbox.io/s/81vxj8lrzl)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectorValues: []
    };

    this.handleKeyUp = this.handleKeyUp.bind(this);
  }

  addSelectorValues = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      selectorValues: [...prevState.selectorValues, ""]
    }));
  };

  removeSelectorValue(index) {
    this.setState({
      selectorValues: this.state.selectorValues.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
    });
  }

  handleSelectorValueChange = index => ({ target: { value } }) => {
    const selectorValues = [...this.state.selectorValues]; //makes separate copy of array.
    selectorValues[index] = value;
    this.setState({ selectorValues });
  };

  handleKeyUp(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      console.log(e.target.value);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { selectorValues } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <fieldset>
            <div>
              <label>Selector Values:</label>{" "}
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={this.addSelectorValues}
                onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp}
              >
                Add
              </button>
              {this.state.selectorValues.map((value, index) => (
                <input
                  key={index}
                  type="text"
                  value={value}
                  placeholder="Enter slector values"
                  onChange={this.handleSelectorValueChange(index)}
                  required
                />
              ))}
              <ul>
                {this.state.selectorValues.map((value, index) => {
                  return (
                    <li key={index}>
                      {value}
                      <button
                        onClick={this.removeSelectorValue.bind(this, index)}
                      >
                        Remove
                      </button>
                    </li>
                  );
                })}
              </ul>
              <br />
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent the form from being submitted:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // They hit enter, which submitted the form.
  // Do anything you need to do here
}
```

See an updated codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wq198q4w08).

Comment: When I click add, a text box appears, type something into the box and hit enter the value disappears. I want the value to be "confirmed".  I already have `e.preventDefault()` in my `handleSubmit` method. So I'm specifically trying to listen to `onKeyUP` inside the `textbox`

Comment: I also don't see any changes in the sandbox you linked.

Comment: Sorry, check again @DJ2

Comment: This is preventing the form from being submitted, but is there a way to handle it with `onKeyUp` so when the `textbox` is in focus, when enter is pressed, the value becomes "confirmed" to the list and another box appears? That is what I'm ultimately looking for.

Comment: IMO, do 2 different forms in that case. One for the adding to the list, and one submitting the actual list. Try to avoid `onKeyUp` handlers at all, they seem like overkill.

Comment: I think in this specific case, I need to use `onKeyUp`. This is just one piece of data in a fairly large form, and the `e.preventDefault` in the submit method is not having the desired behavior within my full application.